# Reading real content of pascal's binary file

Tags: delphi, binary-data, freepascal

I want to know the real content of binary file.
File was created by Deplhi (FreePascal?) based application.

- Filename is FDane.bin
- I don't have source code of this app

After disassembling application i see that (part of disassembled code that contain FDane.bin word):

```
    procedure TFrmDroga.ReadLinesFromFile(Sender : TObject);
begin
(*
005F0BB0   55                     push    ebp
005F0BB1   8BEC                   mov     ebp, esp
005F0BB3   83C4E0                 add     esp, -$20
005F0BB6   53                     push    ebx
005F0BB7   56                     push    esi
005F0BB8   57                     push    edi
005F0BB9   8945FC                 mov     [ebp-$04], eax
005F0BBC   8D75EF                 lea     esi, [ebp-$11]
005F0BBF   33C0                   xor     eax, eax
005F0BC1   55                     push    ebp
005F0BC2   681A135F00             push    $005F131A
005F0BC7   64FF30                 push    dword ptr fs:[eax]
005F0BCA   648920                 mov     fs:[eax], esp

|
005F0BCD   E8DAC4E1FF             call    0040D0AC
005F0BD2   DD1D6C936000           fstp    qword ptr [$0060936C]
005F0BD8   9B                     wait
005F0BD9   B201                   mov     dl, $01

* Reference to class TMemoryStream
|
005F0BDB   A144EB4100             mov     eax, dword ptr [$0041EB44]

|
005F0BE0   E84735E1FF             call    0040412C
005F0BE5   8945F8                 mov     [ebp-$08], eax
005F0BE8   B201                   mov     dl, $01

* Reference to class TMemoryStream
|
005F0BEA   A144EB4100             mov     eax, dword ptr [$0041EB44]

|
005F0BEF   E83835E1FF             call    0040412C
005F0BF4   8945F4                 mov     [ebp-$0C], eax

* Possible String Reference to: 'FDane.bin'
|
005F0BF7   BA30135F00             mov     edx, $005F1330
005F0BFC   8B45F4                 mov     eax, [ebp-$0C]

|
005F0BFF   E8C834E3FF             call    004240CC
005F0C04   6A00                   push    $00
005F0C06   6A00                   push    $00
005F0C08   8B45F8                 mov     eax, [ebp-$08]

|
005F0C0B   E8EC2CE3FF             call    004238FC
005F0C10   6A00                   push    $00
005F0C12   6A00                   push    $00
005F0C14   8B45F4                 mov     eax, [ebp-$0C]

|
005F0C17   E8E02CE3FF             call    004238FC
005F0C1C   8B45F4                 mov     eax, [ebp-$0C]
005F0C1F   8B10                   mov     edx, [eax]
005F0C21   FF12                   call    dword ptr [edx]
005F0C23   85C0                   test    eax, eax
005F0C25   7E3B                   jle     005F0C62
005F0C27   8945E8                 mov     [ebp-$18], eax
005F0C2A   BB01000000             mov     ebx, $00000001
005F0C2F   8BD6                   mov     edx, esi
005F0C31   B901000000             mov     ecx, $00000001
005F0C36   8B45F4                 mov     eax, [ebp-$0C]
005F0C39   8B38                   mov     edi, [eax]

* Possible reference to virtual method TMemoryStream.OFFS_0C
|
005F0C3B   FF570C                 call    dword ptr [edi+$0C]
005F0C3E   8BC3                   mov     eax, ebx
005F0C40   B9C8000000             mov     ecx, $000000C8
005F0C45   99                     cdq
005F0C46   F7F9                   idiv    ecx 
005F0C48   80C220                 add     dl, $20
005F0C4B   3016                   xor     [esi], dl
005F0C4D   8BD6                   mov     edx, esi
005F0C4F   B901000000             mov     ecx, $00000001
005F0C54   8B45F8                 mov     eax, [ebp-$08]
005F0C57   8B38                   mov     edi, [eax]

* Possible reference to virtual method TMemoryStream.OFFS_10
|
005F0C59   FF5710                 call    dword ptr [edi+$10]
005F0C5C   43                     inc     ebx
005F0C5D   FF4DE8                 dec     dword ptr [ebp-$18]
005F0C60   75CD                   jnz     005F0C2F
005F0C62   6A00                   push    $00
005F0C64   6A00                   push    $00
005F0C66   8B45F8                 mov     eax, [ebp-$08]

|
005F0C69   E88E2CE3FF             call    004238FC
005F0C6E   8B45F4                 mov     eax, [ebp-$0C]

|
005F0C71   E80634E3FF             call    0042407C
005F0C76   8B45FC                 mov     eax, [ebp-$04]

* Reference to control TFrmDroga.CDSBrutto : TClientDataSet
|
005F0C79   8B8098040000           mov     eax, [eax+$0498]
005F0C7F   8B55F8                 mov     edx, [ebp-$08]

|
005F0C82   E8A180F0FF             call    004F8D28
005F0C87   8B45FC                 mov     eax, [ebp-$04]

* Reference to control TFrmDroga.CDSBrutto : TClientDataSet
|
005F0C8A   8B8098040000           mov     eax, [eax+$0498]
```

After using 'strings FDane.bin | head -n 50' get (this is a part):

```
    &'(1*+,*.
0120456
82s_f\UM%27
6GFFHIJKLB
>6)5?#
,8-05_^^`abcdn*
srrtuvwxq 
!"#$%hg,)g
./0323446789:;<s~G@ABCDEFGH
BL{~sm
nbfeVWXZZ[\_^_`abcd;&
hijklmno
2ytDDGDD7GMEN
Re,'
2342678?:;<=>?
EEFGHIJK
EPbdchh
klkj[\]V_`aecdefgh)
lnopqrstu
7ryNILAC2
s"!"#$%&'
7896;<=5?@ABCD
KJKLMNOP
^U`aheg
`jlo`abndefkhijklm
0}qstuvwxy
<w~H
&&'()*+,-./61
z89:*<<>?@ABCDEFGHuJKLMNOPQR
doj[\]L_aaccdefghi$+
mnopqrstu(7qyLK@@3C
!"#$%&
Zi +
678/::<8>?@ABC
/IIJKLMNO
YTffgdd
gokn_`aucee`ghijkl
prstuvwx9
;v}MI
b{&%&'()*+
;<=%?AAHCDEFGH
ONOPQRST
RYlklac
\WTSdef{hhj`lmnopq
twxyz{|}
!"#$e
**+,-./0
@ABcDDFHHIJKLMn
QSTUVWXY
V^fPQ^^)YWWXYjklLnnparstuvw8
```

After 200 lines data changes to this:

```
    MKEUNF/0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWV
5797;
ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&7cFFNF
]AAF]V89:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[G
xyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*;gBBJZT
a[FO]KRS^<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_x1)3D,
_R      T
Vyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-.
cTDDBXMHW\
t/-')d
)-)3.$;,n
r)t:x8vYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcU5-7H:
!"#$%&'()*+,-./012-da}
qW\I]NJM5*666$f
4,!9:RSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefgs,
Z(5856
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456:snx
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
iyi|v{123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijkg&9$P93?1846xyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:!f\U
!%;c
?)3'>/k
VWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
ibg#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnoj+"S2'7#+:2:?5^
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>2
        MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrsS&
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@AB_
*6&$'#.l
+#17;!!u
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
OVLJ
aikfh
456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwX#
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFf
-)7o
97>=6,9=y       
55:D6H&Fijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
HDOJG_HB
yegenk
456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{N6
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJB
UVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
idolslr'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNF
YZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

It's looks like there are some character data (I see ASCII up to 127 characters). I'm not a Pascal, Delphi programmer. I know Python, some C and Java. Is it possible to decode ?

Comment: This is like "decoding" 5 back into 2+3.

Comment: maybe you can tell me that this looks like stream of chars or something. That would be useful in usage something like http://wiki.freepascal.org/File

Comment: That file could be anything.  Contact the author of the application that outputs the file and ask them. This is not *please guess the contents of a random binary file*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tips:

The disassembly shows tmemorystream, and then tclientdataset calls. This makes it delphi, and delphi/bcb alone (FreePascal's equivalent is called TBufDataset)

TClientdataset .cds is some proprietary streaming format of a dataset. It might be delphi version dependent. Later (D2010+? rad studio only?) versions come with TClientDataset sources which you could inspect.

Searching for ".cds tclientdataset file format"  might also yield something, and hope it doesn't support encryption.